# How can I make my second selection working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the selection. I am selecting a value and getting the result in an input box, but the problem is, it is only working in the first row of my selection and not working when I am clicking second selection. Here is the code, Please share if you can solve this one or advice.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function displayResult()
    {
        document.getElementById("mycall1").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td><select id = "forcx" onchange="fillgap()"><option>Select</option> <option>Force</option><option>Angle</option><option>Area</option></select></td>';
        document.getElementById("mycall2").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = '<td><input type="text" id="result1" size = "10" ></td>';

        }

        function fillgap(event){
         var xnumb = 20;  
         var forcxlist = document.getElementById("forcx");
         var forcxlistValue = forcxlist.options[forcxlist.selectedIndex].text;  
             if (forcxlistValue == "Force"){
              document.getElementById("result1").value = xnumb;    
     }
     }
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the same ID more than once?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem?  What is the resulting HTML when this doesn't work?  In what way does it "not work"?

Comment: @David Do you have email add i will send it to you, then you can understand what i mean. Only the part not working which i posted but if you want to see the whole code let me know. Thanks

Comment: @user3713336: You have *drastically* misunderstood how Stack Overflow works.  I recommend you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @David I updated my code, now hope you understand. Basically my second row not calling fillgap function

Comment: @user3713336: `"my second row not calling fillgap function"` - The table you're showing only has one row.  Also note that the random and inconsistent spacing/indentation makes it very difficult to follow your code.  It might not be structured the way you think it is?  Clean up the code so it's more easily readable.

Comment: @ David i have button which is inserting row... just copy and paste the code to notepad+ and you will see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if i understand correctly

1) You want to add the: `selection`, `results` & `+` to the existing table

2) Add the options `Force`, `Angle` & `Area` to the `select`

3) If Force is selected, put the value '20' in the results `td`

4) When the `+` is clicked, a new row is added.

5 The newly added rows should behave exactly the same.

Given the above, I have done the following, I'm using jQuery as its simpler and I'm more familiar with it. Its easy.

The trick here is event delegation. at the time your page loads the new rows don't exist, that's why your JavaScript isn't working on them. you can read about it here: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Here's the result:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // add headers to table
  $('table tr:first-child').append('<th>Result</th><th>Add</th>');
  //add fields to table
  $('table tr:not(:first-child)').append('<td><select class="selection"><option></option><option value="Force">Force</option><option value="Angle">Angle</option><option value="Area">Area</option></select></td><td class="result"></td><td><button type="button" class="displayResultBtn">+</button></td>');
  
  // add new row when button is clicked
  $('table').on('click','.displayResultBtn', function( event) {
    var tRow = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
    $(this).parents('table').append(tRow);
    $('table tr:last-child td.result').empty();
    
  });

  // when the dropdown is changed, update the result to 20 if "Force" is selected.
  $('table').on('change','.selection', function( event) {
    var selection = $(this).val();
    if (selection == "Force") {
      $(this).parent().next().html('20');
      // You can add more coditionals if you want to add didferent values for the other options.
    } else {
     $(this).parent().next().empty();
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 30%;
  table-layout: auto;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>To</th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>Detail</th>
    <th>Selection</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>A+B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have whole code, so i can understand it better. Cause your html code above doesn't match with jquery code. So i can't even understand

Comment: My code in this answer works, there is nothing else.

Comment: Do you want to skype and go through it together? I want to help you but i fear we a misunderstanding eachother

Comment: ya sure what's your id i will call you on skype

Comment: one question.. just want to know did you put the whole code together... or i am missing something here

Comment: brad.chellingworth

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer with limited code provided, but I think your issue is that you are using `id` multiple times. Which is invalid. `id` should be unique and used once only.

I have put together some demo code here that will hopefully help you. It doesn't solve your exact problem(I dont have your html so i cant fully solve it). but hopefully this will give you an idea of how to handle accessing different rows, or specific unique ids.

I'm using jQuery here for simplicity, but the principle is the same:

Here's a fiddle if thats easier to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/BradChelly/4179e26q/

I hope this helps somewhat.

```js
// highlight row by child selectors (:last-child)
$('#selectLastRowBtn').click(function(){
  //clear any previous highlighting
 $('#myTable tr:not(:first-child)').css('background-color','white');
  // highlight the last row in the table.
 $('#myTable tr:last-child').css('background-color','lightgrey');
});

// highlight row using a specific unique id
$('#selectRowByIdBtn').click(function(){
 //get selected row id from dropdown
  var rowId = $('#rowSelector option:selected').val();
  //clear any previous highlighting
 $('#myTable tr:not(:first-child)').css('background-color','white');
 //highlight the row with the matching id from the selection dropdown
  $('#myTable #row_'+rowId).css('background-color','lightgrey');
});

//
//  ------Below is just stuff to make demo work, not relevant to the question
//

// Add row with unique id
$('#addNewRowBtn').click(function(){
 var rowCount = $('#myTable tr').length;
 $('#myTable').append('<tr id="row_'+rowCount+'"><td>23124</td><td>23124</td><td>23124</td><td>23124</td></tr>');
  populateSelect(rowCount);
});

// populate select options
function populateSelect(rowCount){
 $('#rowSelector').append('<option value="'+rowCount+'">'+rowCount+'</option>')
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 30px 0px;
}

table tr:first-child {
  top: 0px;
  background: #333;
}

table tr:first-child th {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Column One</th>
    <th>Column Two</th>
    <th>Column Three</th>
    <th>Column Four</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_1">
    <td>23124</td>
    <td>23124</td>
    <td>23124</td>
    <td>23124</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="addNewRowBtn">Add Row</button>
<h3>Using child selectors:</h3>
<button id="selectLastRowBtn">Highlight last row using child selector</button>

<h3>Highlight a row by id:</h3>

<select name="" id="rowSelector">
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<button id="selectRowByIdBtn">Highlight row by selected id</button>
```

Comment: yes because if you are selecting an element by id, and multiple elements have that id its going to only select the first 1. Having multiple elements with the same id is invalid HTML. either give each new row a unique id or use classes and child selectors. If you paste your HTML or even better a fiddle demonstrating what you are trying to achieve it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: @user3713336 I have update my answer hopefully explaining in more detail the use of ids

Comment: @ Brad i have update my code and you can see what i mean... your code is confusing i am not understanding. Order to make your code work i have to change my whole logic. Can you see my code and tell me is there any way i can fix or get the value when i add second row

Comment: Your missing the point, my demo above was to show the nature of using id and selectors. Your problem here is a couple of things. you have tables nested within tables which just seems wrong to me, you have functions that add elements with hard coded ids, meaning your adding the same id multiple times which is invalid. Lastly, its not clear what your trying to do.

Comment: So is it the case, you dont have access to the body, but you want to add a select dropwdown in the "selection" column? Then if the value of that selection is "Force" then the result should = 20?

Comment: yes you're correct so first row when i am adding selection "Force" its giving me the result 20 but next row (second row) not giving me the value 20 when i am selecting Force

Comment: So in your body, does the columns  `<th>Result</th>`  `<th>Add</th>` exist? or are you creating them?

Comment: yes those exist.. only i am creating <td>result</td> which is input box and trying to print 20. it is printing on the first row but not on the second row. Can you please run it by saving in html... then you will understand what i mean